# can ∀(∃,(≠∧∀((,)→(=∨=)))) be rewritten as: ∃,(≠∧∀(∀(,)→(=∨=)))?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

*Can* **∀(∃,(≠∧∀((,)→(=∨=))))**   *be rewritten as* **∃,(≠∧∀(∀(,)→(=∨=)))**

*as i can shift the **∀** towards **H(z,r)**, since there are no other "r" variables in the expression.*

Comment: No, it's the same difference as between a continuous function and an uniformly continuous function.

Comment: Instead of playing confusing games with logical rules, try just thinking about what it means.

Comment: What if the domain is the set of all living people, and $H(z,r)$ means that $z$ is a (biological) parent of $r$? Is the first sentence true? Is the second?

Comment: @bof good way to deal with logic statements but not always.. as sometimes the logic statements become too long and hard to look at its meaning every time we want to apply a logic rule to it so logic rules are needed

Comment: You are right, but I don't think you've reached that point in this problem.

Comment: Can you state the "logic rule" you used to justify your rewrite?

Comment: @bof yeah I mean in *general case* not in this problem